# Writing a simple image browser using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to write a simple image browser. User taps a button, `UIImagePicker` springs up, user selects photo, large detail gets displayed, user taps a ‘back’ button and is back in the picker. Everything is quite easy except the last part, the returning to the picker. The picker is a modal view, so that I have to dismiss it in order to display the picture detail. Once I dismiss it, though, I cannot easily return to it. (I’d have to reopen it and user would get back to the index instead of the last album open.) I tried keeping the picker open, but then my navigation controller’s `pushViewController` method does not work when I try to push the picture detail. What am I doing wrong? How would you write such a simple gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that was easy. I have to push the picture detail onto the picker, not on the main navigation controller.